# Can I import my MySQL data into Google Spanner?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I tried to import a `mysqldump` generated .sql file but Google spanner didn't accept the syntax, which makes sense.

With that, we're trying to migrate our data, which is in a MySQL data, into Google cloud spanner. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a project that I used to upload my (test) data to Cloud Spanner from a PostgreSQL database: https://github.com/olavloite/spanner-jdbc-converter. It uses standard JDBC functionality, so it should be easy to adapt it to work with MySQL as well.

Another possibility, if the database you're trying to upload is not very big, would be to use a standard database tool that allows you to copy data from JDBC compliant database to another. DBeaver supports this feature. Have a look here for how to set up DBeaver with Google Cloud Spanner: http://www.googlecloudspanner.com/2017/10/using-standard-database-tools-with.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Harbourbridge](https://github.com/cloudspannerecosystem/harbourbridge) to migrate both schema and data to Cloud Spanner from a MySQL source.